# Is it possible to set video from device camera as background in Unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm implementing an augmented reality prototype. But I have not figured out how to set video as background. There is a [WebCamTexture](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.html) class which can be set as a texture for GUITexture. But in this case other 3d objects are not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a plane
2. Attach it to Camera Node
3. GameObject->Align View to Selected
4. Translate the plane to 900
5. Scale the plane to fit the screen.

Answer (score 0):

create 2 cameras, one set to view all the 3d object , the other with the GUITexture.

Answer (score 0):

Attach following code to your main camera and you are done

```
public class webcam_example : MonoBehaviour
{
    WebCamTexture webcamTexture;
    bool webcam_ok = false;
    void Start()
    {
        WebCamDevice[] webCams = WebCamTexture.devices;
        if (webCams.Length > 0) {
           webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture();
           webcamTexture.Play();
           webcam_ok = true;
        }
    }

    void OnPreRender()
    {
        if (webcam_ok)
        {
            Graphics.Blit(webcamTexture, (RenderTexture)null);
        }
    }
}
```